# VBA Listbox: Check if listbox items are already in specified worksheet range and write listbox item in next empty cell

Tags: vba, listbox, listboxitem, is-empty

Title seems a bit complicated, but I'll try explaining with steps (what I want VBA code to do):

1. Read only one list item from the list
2. If this item is already in 1st Column (Columns(1)) in my worksheet, skip steps 3. and 4.
3. If this item is not in the 1st column (Columns(1)) check for the first empty cell in that column (reading from the top)
4. When next empty cell has been found copy the item that is not already in this column in that empty cell
5. Proceed to the next item

What I have so far is the following code:

```
Private Sub Tab1_Done_Button_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim listItem As Variant  

    For listItem = 0 To Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.ListCount - 1
          'Check If The Product Is Already There (Dont't Create Duplicate)
           For i = 4 To 400
           If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.List(listItem) Then
                   'Write In First Empty Cell In 1st Column If Not Duplicate
                   For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
                       If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                            cell.Value = Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.List(listItem)
                            Exit For
                       End If
                   Next cell
                   Exit For
             End If
        Next i
    Next listItem
End Sub
```

I have obviously made a logical mistake somewhere here, as what happens is the following:

I already have Product 3, Product 5 and Product 6 in the first column. I go to the listbox in my form and after several actions I end up with the following items in the listbox: Product 3, Product 6 and Product 7. What I would expect the code to do is to now transfer only Product 7 in the next empty cell in the 1st column, but what it currenlty does is that it still transfers all the products from listbox and after all this is what I have in the first column: Product 3, Product 5, Product 6, Product 3, Product 6, Product 7.
This means that the code is able to recognize the empty cells in the first row, it is able to read the data from listbox, it is able to copy the data from listbox and paste it in empty cells as desired, **but is unable to check whether the product from the listbox is already in one of the cells in the 1st column.**

Thank you in advance for any advice on how I could fix the part where code needs to check for the duplicates.

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrote the code in another way, so now it does what it is supposed to. Tested and all works correctly:

```
Range("A:A").Select
        For listItem = 0 To Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.ListCount - 1
                If Selection.Find(What:=Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.List(listItem), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    For Each cell In Columns(1).Cells
                        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                            cell.Value = Me.Tab1_Product_Picked.List(listItem)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next cell
                End If
        Next listItem
```

I'll just leave this here in case anyone ever encounters the same problem :)